# Target second (or nth) element in a for loop

Tags: templating, forloop

I'm trying to show content for only the second entry in a for loop, but can't find any info on how to do specifically this. I'd like to do something like the below.

```
{% for relatedImage in entry.relatedImages %}
    {% for images in relatedImage.image %}
        <div>
            <a href="{{ relatedImage.url }}">
                <img src="{{ images.getUrl('default') }}" alt="{{ relatedImage.title }}" width="{{ images.getWidth('default') }}" height="{{ images.getHeight('default') }}" />
             </a>{% if loop.index == 2 %}<div><h2>Welcome!</h2></div>{% endif %}
         </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you're using `loop.index` in the context of the inner loop.

Based on your comment, there will only ever be one images selected, so `loop.index` will never be 2.

If you don't want to move the `loop.index` check to the outer loop, then a simple counter will work:

```
{% set counter = 0 %}

{% for relatedImage in entry.relatedImages %}
    {% set counter = counter + 1 %}

    {% for images in relatedImage.image %}
        <div>
            <a href="{{ relatedImage.url }}">
                <img src="{{ images.getUrl('default') }}" alt="{{ relatedImage.title }}" width="{{ images.getWidth('default') }}" height="{{ images.getHeight('default') }}" />
             </a>{% if counter == 2 %}<div><h2>Welcome!</h2></div>{% endif %}
         </div>
    {% endfor %}


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah no, relatedImages are entries with one image in each of those entries.

Comment: Well, not quite as i need the content of that {if} inside the div inside the loop. Is it possible to implement a counter in the outer loop (like in php $1++) that i can inspect in the inner loop?

Comment: Yup... updated answer.

Comment: Aha! For some reason my googling let me down there. Cheers, your Bradness!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the twig [loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

```
{% for relatedImage in entry.relatedImages %}
  {% for images in relatedImage.image %}
    <blah {% if loop.index == 2%}class="i'm the second"{% endif %} >
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

There are a number of useful loop variables: `first`, `last`, `index`, `revindex`, `length`.

Comment: I tried exactly that and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am a little suspicious of your nested for loops. If the `relatedImages` field is just a regular asset, then you only need the outer loop.

Comment: Let me show the full code and you can tell me better if that is the case? I'll edit the question.

Comment: There, updated, it's an asset field with multiple images in it.

Comment: I think you just need the single loop:

    {% for relatedImage in entry.relatedImages %}
      <div>
        <a href="{{ relatedImage.url }}">
          <img src="{{ relatedImage.getUrl('default') }}" alt="{{ relatedImage.title }}" width="{{ relatedImage.getWidth('default') }}" height="{{ relatedImage.getHeight('default') }}" />
        </a>
        {% if loop.index == 2 %}<div><h2>Welcome!</h2></div>{% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}

Comment: I tried that, it didn't like it!

Comment: Does this work to loop over the images?

    {% for relatedImage in entry.relatedImages %}
      {{loop.index}}: {{relatedImage.title}}
    {% endfor %}

Comment: Again no, i don't see how your code can work tbh, it needs to loop over the images in the field, your code is trying to access the field once. From what i can see anyway.